# echo text alongside a generated value PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, response

I'm using this line of php in my main page

```
    echo generateRadioButtons("fbresponse.php", "moRating1", 6);
```

Which when posting the following on the response file

```
echo $_POST['moRating1']
```

It works fine and displays the correct result, but! my question is how would i   add text to that so..

Blah blah blah, you rated x question: 'moRating1'

I've tried doing

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Questions</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Survey responses</h1>
<p>How well did you rate it : <?php print $moRating1 ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

inside the response file but that just doesnt load anything..

Any help please!

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because this function uses `eval()` to execute its content (I guess it from lack of PHP tags in your first example).

If it's true, then you should be able to close PHP tag, print HTML and open it again.

```
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Questions</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Survey responses</h1>
        <p>How well did you rate it : <?php print $_POST['moRating1'] ?></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try doing:

```
 $mRating1 = $_POST['moRating1'];
 ...
 ?>
 ...
 <p>How well did you rate it: <?php echo $mRating1?></p>
```